# C++ Micro Second Timer with parallel thread in Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: c++, multithreading, ubuntu, timer, parallel-processing

I created a timer and called for every 0.1 Millisecond. It's working good.
But problem faced a Thread calling from timer. The timer calling infinite time.

I like to process 2 parallel thread or process inside the timer(with 0.1 millisec). Is this possible? I'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Sample code as follows

```
int main(void)
{
    if (start_timer(0.1, &timer_handler)) //0.1 millisec timer caleed
    {
        printf("\n timer error\n");
        return(1);
    }
    while (1)
    {
        if (var > 10)       break;
    }
    stop_timer();
    return 0;
}

void timer_handler(void)
{
    int ret = 0;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, Test_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread, (void **)&ret);
    printf("test_thread : %d\n", ret);
}

void *Test_thread(void *arg)
{
    pthread_exit((void*)cnt++);
}
```

Comment: what's `start_timer()` and `stop_timer()`?

Comment: And what is `timer_handler`? You gave only `timer_handler1` definition. Btw, why did you tag it with `c++` when there is `c` only code.

Comment: start_timer() and stop_timer() these two functions are calling from timer.c file.

Comment: typing mistake - timer_handler instead of timer_handler1. yes I was convert my code from c to cpp. Its c/cpp no issue for me if logic works.